# How to display the row by greatest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005

**Table1**

```
ID Date Value

001 23/01/2012 100
002 24/02/2012 200
002 21/01/2012 300
003 18/02/2012 200
003 19/02/2012 100
...
```

I want to display max(date) for each id.  How to do this.

I Tried

`Select id, max(date), value from table group by id, value`

but Output showing all the rows

**Expected Output**

```
ID Date Value

001 23/01/2012 100
002 24/02/2012 200
003 19/02/2012 100
...
```

Need SQL Query Help

Comment: Do group by id only. No need for group by value and also remove value from the select part otherwise it will throw error

Comment: What should happen if an ID appears twice on the same (and greatest) day?

Answer (score 1):

using Rank over:

```
select id,
date, value from (
select id,
date, value,
Rank() over (Partition BY ID order by date DESC) rank
from Table1) a
where a.rank = 1
```

Comment: +1  I suspect the OP may actually want ROW_NUMBER()ing, rather than RANK()ing, with ties broken by `value` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
with CTE as 
(
Select Id, MAX(Date) as maxdate
from table1 
Group by Id
)
Select t1.ID, t1.Maxdate, t2.Value
from CTE t1, Table1 t2
where t1.ID = t2.ID
and t1.maxdate = t2.date;
```

[Demo sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cfed/12)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT id, date, value 
FROM table1, (SELECT id, max(date) FROM table1 GROUP BY id) t
WHERE table1.id =t.id AND table1.date=t.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Option with [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) + [RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function

```
;WITH cte AS
(
 SELECT id, date, value,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
 FROM Table1
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM cte
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3282/1)

Option with [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) operator

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date, t1.value
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS(
             SELECT 1
             FROM Table1 t2
             WHERE t1.id = t2.id
             HAVING MAX(t2.date) = t1.date
             )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd0ef/1)

Option with [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date, t1.value
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS APPLY (
                            SELECT 1 AS 'IsMatch'
                            FROM Table1 t2
                            WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                            HAVING MAX(t2.date) = t1.date
                            ) o
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3282/2)